# Printing a variable containing a hash doesn't give me any output

Tags: bash

I have a file with contents like this:

```
FOO=#{Foo}

# may contain blank lines or lines with comments
BAR=#{Bar}
```

Now, I want to do some stuff with those that requires me to consider `FOO` and `#{Foo}` as separate entities. So I tried the following, to ensure that I get the data I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  variable="${line%\=*}"
  toReplace="${line#*\=}"

  echo "$toReplace"
  printf "%s -> \$%s\n" "$toReplace" "$variable"
done < <(grep '=' myfile)
```

This outputs, to my great surprise, the following:

```
#{Foo}
 -> $FOO
#{Bar}
 -> $BAR
```

As you see, the `toReplace` part of the line is not printed, although it is apparently extracted correctly.

I also tried `echo -n "$toReplace"`, which printed nothing.

Why is this? What can I do about it?

Comment: Can you post the output of `hexdump -c myfile` and `file myfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the input file has MSWin line ends. The special character `$'\r'` gets interpreted as "goto line start", so `-> $FOO` overwrites the `$toReplace` part.

Run the input file through `dos2unix` or `fromdos`.

Comment: Thanks - would never have thought about this! Since this is a script that will run in a CI environment, where I want to install as few things as possible, I'll remove them with `sed 's/\r$//g'` instead of `dos2unix` or `fromdos`, but this does solve my problem.